# Is discussion of statistics jobs & qualifications off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm mainly thinking about [this question ("Is my learnings in Machine Learning fine?")](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/112951/36229) which was put on hold for being off-topic.

What I'm wondering is: would this question still be off-topic if the asker had targeted the question to something like, "Are these qualifications suitable for a job in statistics?" or, "What kinds of statistics jobs am I qualified for?"

Comment: The reason given for being off topic was "It is not answerable: it asks for opinions about your capabilities." Your last suggestion would not cure that subjectivity. As far as "qualifications" go, the question recounts the OP's efforts to learn but has no information whatsoever about qualifications. Hypothetically, if it did, then we would still be in the dark about what kind of "job" is meant, making the question too broad to be answerable. These shortcomings possibly detract from what you might really want to ask here, so perhaps it would be better not to reference that question at all.

Comment: I think that actually answers my question.

Comment: The answer to your title question is, "Jobs are often on-topic" -- see `career` [tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/careers). In the body of your question, you asked something different and narrow, and whuber gave a complete answer to that.

Comment: Interesting.  I found, as an engineer, that there were skills that I wish I had, gaps in my university education that I had to hand-fix instead of having them instutitionally built into my program.  Hand fixing is harder.  Is it acceptable to ask what sort of strengths/talents/skills are desirable in the current market, or where market trends suggest leading skills developed today will find excellent and only half-expected fit tomorrow?